# Using powershell how to extract a number from a list

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a file with git commits,

```
c2b7b1913 Merged PR 38064: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
baa810a57 Merged PR 37937: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
8d67d563c Merged PR 37825: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
2a061da0b Merged PR 37494: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

How do I use powershell to get just the PR number, i.e. I would like

```
38064
37937
37825
37494
```

Here is my attempts

```
Get-Content .\testdata.txt `
| Select-String -Pattern "^.*Merged PR (\d{5}):.*$" -AllMatches `
| ForEach-Object {$_.Matches.Groups}
```

Which seems to return the correct data. Below is the output. But how do I get to the regex group?

```
Groups   : {0, 1}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 0
Length   : 54
Value    :  c2b7b1913 Merged PR 38064: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

Success  : True
Name     : 1
Captures : {1}
Index    : 21
Length   : 5
Value    : 38064

Groups   : {0, 1}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 0
Length   : 54
Value    :  baa810a57 Merged PR 37937: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

Success  : True
Name     : 1
Captures : {1}
Index    : 21
Length   : 5
Value    : 37937

Groups   : {0, 1}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 0
Length   : 54
Value    :  8d67d563c Merged PR 37825: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

Success  : True
Name     : 1
Captures : {1}
Index    : 21
Length   : 5
Value    : 37825

Groups   : {0, 1}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 0
Length   : 54
Value    :  2a061da0b Merged PR 37494: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

Success  : True
Name     : 1
Captures : {1}
Index    : 21
Length   : 5
Value    : 37494
```

Here is the equivalent `sed` command

```
sed -nE 's/^.*Merged PR ([[:digit:]]{5}):.*$/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use split:

```
gc C:\tmp\testdata.txt | %{($_ -split " ")[3] -replace ":"}
```

Or back to your version:

```
$data = gc C:\tmp\testdata.txt | Select-String -Pattern "(\d{5})" -AllMatches
$data.matches.groups.value
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get them by accessing `.Groups[1].Value` property:

```
Get-Content Get-Content .\testdata.txt `
 | Select-String -Pattern "Merged PR (\d{5}):" -AllMatches `
 | ForEach-Object {$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}
```

Note the `^.*` and `.*$` parts are not necessary because PowerShell regex matching does not require a complete string to match the pattern.

With `Merged PR (\d{5}):` regex, you match `Merged PR`  substring and *capture* into a separate group five digits (with `(\d{5})`) that are immediately followed with a `:` char. So, once captured, you just access the right group value in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `Get-Content`, `Select-String` supports the path parameter:

```
Select-String -Path <path> -Pattern '(?<=PR\s)[0-9]+' | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.value }
```

```
(?<=PR\s)[0-9]+

(?<=PR\s) : Find PR in string with 1 whitespace but dont include it in result, example - 'PR '
[0-9]+  : 1 or more digits
```

Example:

```
<#
    File contents ion C:\tmp\testmsg.txt
    c2b7b1913 Merged PR 38064: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    baa810a57 Merged PR 37937: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    8d67d563c Merged PR 37825: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    2a061da0b Merged PR 37494: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
#>

Select-String -Path C:\tmp\testmsg.txt -Pattern '(?<=PR\s)[0-9]+' | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }

38064
37937
37825
37494
```